# Convert SQL into Doctrine 2 QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need help to convert a valid SQL query into `createQueryBuilder`. The problem I have is I don't know how to `LEFT JOIN` on a `SELECT` in the `createQueryBuilder`.

```
SELECT username, count(c.user_owner_id) as num_contact, a_g.name as 
       group_name 
       FROM `oro_user` as u 
       INNER JOIN `oro_user_access_group` as u_g on u.id=u_g.user_id    
       INNER JOIN `oro_access_group` as a_g on u_g.group_id=a_g.id 
       LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT cc.user_owner_id 
              FROM `orocrm_contact` as cc 
              INNER JOIN`orocrm_contact_to_contact_grp` as cc_g on cc_g.contact_id=cc.id 
              INNER JOIN `orocrm_contact_group` 
                    as c_g on cc_g.contact_group_id=c_g.id  
              WHERE  c_g.label='New One' and cc.semester_contacted='2017A') 
      as c on u.id=c.user_owner_id 
      WHERE a_g.name='Full-timer' and u.enabled = 1 and u.gender='male' 
      GROUP BY u.id 
      ORDER BY num_contact
```

I have two queries below, I want user to `LEFT JOIN` the results from contact

```
 $user = $this->em->getRepository('OroUserBundle:User')->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u.username')
        ->innerJoin('u.groups','g')
        ->andWhere('g.name = :group')
        ->setParameter('group', 'Full-timer')
        ->getQuery();

 $contacts = $this->em->getRepository('OroContactBundle:Contact')->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c')
        ->innerJoin('c.groups','g')
        ->andWhere('g.label = :group')
        ->andWhere('c.semester_contacted = :sem')
        ->setParameter('group', 'New One')
        ->setParameter('sem', '2017A')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty complex queries and since the ORM QueryBuilder works closer to your entities than the database I'm not sure if you can just "dump" the DQL into a `->join()`. The good news with the [DBAL QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) that works:

```
$dbalQueryBuilder
    ->from('user_table as u')
    ...
    ->join('u', '('.$otherDbalQueryBuilder->getSQL().')', 'c')
```

This is from memory so it might be a little different, but something like that.

With that you can get all the fields you require, but you won't get any entities. Luckily [Doctrine provides ways to build entities from Native SQL using ResultSetMapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).

```
$userWithContacts = $entityManager->createNativeQuery(
    $dbalQueryBuilder->getSQL(),
    $yourResultSetMapping
);
```

I know this is will require more code and is probably not as nice as just using the ORM QueryBuilder, but I find it oftentimes to be the best way to deal with existing queries that need to be ported to ORM somehow.